# A tikz picture with a lot of nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-positioning

I want to create a tikz picture that describes the different mark ups the user sees inside the lyx editor:

[image]

**First question**: The way I do it is placing on the canvas a few `node`s that together form the image. But I am afraid that my approach may work, but is not clever.

I am creating a node `t1`, which is the top-most element. Then I create a new one, `t2` that is placed below or to the left etc. of the former one, `t1`. Then `t3` is created and placed somewhere relative to `t2`, and so on.

But what if reckon later that `t2` should actually be deleted? Then I should rename all the other nodes that appear after it.

So I would like to hear the site member's opinion about a more correct way of creating such a tikz picture.

**Second question**: I want the tikzpicture to spread all over the `textwidth` of the page. How can I make the beige area to be of width `textwidth`?

**Third question**: The two words "this" of the first two lines in the screenshot are vertically aligned (blue dashed line indicates it). How can I do it in my tikz drawing as well?

MWE:

```latex
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,backgrounds}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\Times{Times New Roman}[Script=Latin,Language=English]
\newfontfamily\courier{Courier New}[Script=Latin,Language=English]

\definecolor{beige}{RGB}{250,240,229}
\definecolor{RedBerry}{RGB}{141,0,0}
\definecolor{Chestnut}{RGB}{207,91,90}
\begin{document}
This is the interface of the LyX editor:

\begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={fill=beige}, show background rectangle,every node/.append style={font=\Times}]
\node (t1)  {~~~This is the LyX editor.};
\node (t2) [below left=16pt and 0pt of t1.south west, anchor=west] {\bfseries\huge{1~~~~This is a section}};
\node (t3) [below=4pt of t2] {This line is not indented. ~};
\node (t4) [right=0pt of t3.base east, anchor=base west,draw=Chestnut] {\textcolor{RedBerry}{\courier{and this is ERT code}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would do the LaTeX using LaTeX and align the tikzpicture elements using `\tikzmark`s.  To add a color background, see `\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{...}`.

Comment: What do you mean "I would do the latex using latex"?

Comment: Just print the text rather than use nodes, except for comments (or whatever ERT mode is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that it would be much easier to implement the idea of showing LyX's editor in a pdf using `tcolorbox` rather than `tikz`.  This way you can create an environment for the LyX GUI and create a box for the ERT code which can used many times throughout the document, with much shorter code.

For example:

```latex
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\Times{Times New Roman}[Script=Latin,Language=English]
\newfontfamily\courier{Courier New}[Script=Latin,Language=English]

\definecolor{beige}{RGB}{250,240,229}
\definecolor{RedBerry}{RGB}{141,0,0}
\definecolor{Chestnut}{RGB}{207,91,90}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\LyX}{L\kern-.1667em\lower.25em\hbox{Y}\kern-.125emX\@}% the LyX symbol.
\makeatother

\newlength\myspace
\settowidth{\myspace}{\Large\bfseries 1\quad}% this is the length of the section number and the space after it

\newtcolorbox{LyXbox}{%
enhanced,breakable,frame hidden,
sharp corners,colback=beige,boxsep=3pt,
before skip=1pt
}
\newtcbox{\ERT}{%
    enhanced,tcbox raise base,
    top=0mm,bottom=0mm,
    right=0mm,left=0mm,
    boxrule=0.4pt,
    nobeforeafter,
    colframe=Chestnut,
    fontupper=\courier\color{RedBerry},
    colback=beige,boxsep=1pt,
    sharp corners
}

\begin{document}
    \noindent This is the interface of the \LyX\ editor:
    \begin{LyXbox}
        \hspace{\myspace}This is the \LyX\ editor.
        \section{This is a section}
        This line is not indented. \ERT{and this is ERT code}
    \end{LyXbox}
\end{document}
```

yields the following result (by default the tcolorbox is the width of `\textwidth`).

[image]